# BigBlueButton integration - “Authentication failed due to missing credentials.”

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core, bigbluebutton

We are analyzing to integrate BigBlueButton as part of our existing web site. So we tried the APIs available in https://mconf.github.io/api-mate/ .

Especially, we used api/create to create meeting and tried to join the meeting as moderator using the following API

http://test-install.blindsidenetworks.com/bigbluebutton/api/join?fullName=User+680453&meetingID=random-3862462&password=mp&redirect=true&checksum=ea0fb12ed57128bfd5b1e1a2b56625f5273a04b6 and it is working as expected. We are able to join the meeting.

Since the requirement here is to integrate the BigBlueButton as part of existing web site, we set the redirect a false as below

http://test-install.blindsidenetworks.com/bigbluebutton/api/join?fullName=User+680453&meetingID=random-3862462&password=mp&redirect=true&checksum=ea0fb12ed57128bfd5b1e1a2b56625f5273a04b6
and got the response as given below

```
<response>
    <returncode>SUCCESS</returncode>
    <messageKey>successfullyJoined</messageKey>
    <message>You have joined successfully.</message>
    <meeting_id>92e808d77b86f2d0db55ef3cc0d222340849726-1597920882558</meeting_id>
    <user_id>w_b2zox8uw2zbs</user_id>
    <auth_token>uxremaweed4o</auth_token>
    <session_token>kpu6clqlz0gavo</session_token>
    <guestStatus>ALLOW</guestStatus>
    <url>https://t008.rna1.blindsidenetworks.com/html5client/join?sessionToken=kpu6clqlz0gavo</url>
</response>
```

Later then we tried to iframe the url

```
<iframe src="https://m067.rna1.blindsidenetworks.com/html5client/join?sessionToken=kpu6clqlz0gavo"></iframe>
```

When I opened the html file, it is throwing "**Authentication failed due to missing credentials.**" error as given below

[image]

So how do we integrate BigBlueButton in a angular site?

Also, if someone help me to understand even if the URL is shared, how to ensure only the authorized users in our web site is able to join the meeting?

In our application backend API is .NetCore and front end is Angular.

Answer (score 0):

The Join request should be made from the client side/Browser

So you just need to pass the whole Big blue button Join URL with Checksum and redirect = true so whenever someone want to join they will redirect to the meeting directly.

Comment: I understand, but I want the meeting to happen inside my application (integrated experience) without navigating to another site or another tab. That is the reason why I am trying with iFrame.

Answer (score 0):

Because there's this Third-party Cookie Blocking in the browser that leads the bbb's cookie which holds the auth data blocked.

according to this [Github Issue](https://github.com/bigbluebutton/bigbluebutton/issues/9998) there's possible workaround:

1. In `/usr/share/bbb-web/WEB-INF/classes/bigbluebutton.properties` set `allowRequestsWithoutSession` to `true`
2. Use nginx's `proxy_cookie_path`

I've only used the #1 workaround to embed my bbb room inside an iframe, so I couldn't explains more detail about the other.